# Java regex missing values

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I must confess, I'm pretty useless when it comes to writing regular expressions, but I've currently got a problem that's really confusing me.

I have written a function that takes a string as input (22K in size) and performs a single regex on it, looking for Long values.  One a long value has been found, it is replaced with a String value from a hashmap.

However, it keeps on missing values within the String, the regex I have written is:

```
Pattern.compile("[*]{3}[0-9]{1,}[*]{3}");
```

The long values I'm searching for in the file are formatted as such:

```
***nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn***
```

Now the regex seems to work, but like I said, it misses some values, for example:

```
***1407374883553285*** - FOUND
***281474976720057*** - NOT FOUND
```

I'm really quite confused as to why it's missing values, I'm using a simple while loop to do the search, and `matcher.find()` for when it does match.

I'm assuming that either my regex isn't strict enough, or it's missing values due to the way the data is structured in the input string.

If anyone can offer any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Is some of your `*'s` common at the ends for both numbers? Can you show your code and some part of your original input?

Comment: Regex is fine (yet it could also be [*]{3}[0-9]+[*]{3} ). Probably related to input string. Any chance to check a fragment with one of the missing values? Have you tried using an input with a fragment including one of the missed values?

Comment: Your regex should work. The only possible explanation is that you may have some garbage invisible character somewhere in the text.

Comment: Your regex works fine for me. Could you show us how you use it? I mean some Java code that reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why do you say the second sample is not found ? is it because it is not found or because it was not replaced ? (if it is the second reason : double check your replacement code)

Comment: You can simplify your regex a little: `Pattern.compile("\*{3}\d+\*{3}");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner regex is `[*]{3}\d+[*]{3}`.  Check it against the following to see how it goes:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[*]{3}\\d+[*]{3}");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("inputfile");
while (matcher.find())
{
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape your asterixis in your character classes. Replace `[\*]` with `[*]`, or just remove the square brackets altogether: `\*`

Comment: Thanks jgm, I just spotted the problem, there was some garbage data getting into the string somehow, I've just taken it out, put in your regex and now it's working.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Cerbrus: It depends, `[*]` might be easier to read for some people. But `[\\*]` is definitely redundant.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yep don't need the backslash.  But I do prefer to use `[*]` over `\*`, because it's more maintainable and, IMO, more readable.  Thanks.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Imo, `[*]` is just a little silly, but that's a personal preference. In Java, `\\*` or `[*]` are both 3 characters, so whatever they want, right? :P

Comment: @jgm: As long as you don't use `[\\*]`, I'm happy :P

Answer (score -1):

You can use `java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(String regEx, CharSequence input)` with regualar expression as "`[*]{3}[0-9]*[*]{3}`"

Comment: `[0-9]{1,}` != `[0-9]*` Also this doesn't answer OP question.

Comment: Same comment as the other answer: Just remove the square brackets altogether: `\*`, and what @Pshemo said.